# Slow ASP.NET Map Handler - Compile ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis

I have performance iisue with **ASP.NET Map Handler**. I have two folders with .aspx pages. When application is first load after computer is restart (startup), and user switch between one page in first folder to another page in second folder - it takes long time (8 second on image). I use ASP.NET web application project which is always precompiled. And debug mode is release. Why is runing **ASP.NET Compile** on image (performance monitor) ???

[image: Perfomance monitor]

Comment: From what monitoring/profiling app is this breakdown coming from?  Sorry, I just don't recognize it.

Comment: [ASP.NET Perfecto use Performance monitor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josere/archive/2010/04/09/taking-a-quick-peek-at-the-performance-of-your-asp-net-app.aspx)

Comment: The image link you provided appears to be broken.  But to answer the question without seeing it:  is it possible that what you're seeing is the compile, not of the page-behinds into a library, but of the .aspx and .ascx files into the runtime code?  This tends to run on first access of a page.

Answer (score 0):

The results you are seeing are basically in line with the behaviour I expect from ASP.NET. 8 seconds startup is pretty standard for the first request at application start.

You may wish to look into [ASP.NET Precompilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which may or may not help you - you'll have to try (I've experienced variable results).

Comment: Thanks, but I use ASP.NET web application project (not web site project), which is always precompiled ... It isn't first request after restart. It is first request, which page load from another folder.